# How to add a unique name to a FileField that stores in aws s3?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-models

I am having an issue with s3. When another user uploads a File which contains same name, the old one gets deleted and replaced with the new one. How can i add a unique name as a filename?

Here is my settings.py

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'my access key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'my secret key here'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-media'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Designer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False,
                            help_text='Designer Unique Name')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    mobileNumber = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    logo = models.FileField(blank=True) # How to add a unique name??
```

Answer (score 1):

[Override model's save() method.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) Check if a file with same name exists, if so, you can append some random characters (or you may append username if you like) to filename to make it unique and save it that way. It is pretty similar to slug saving.